# How I can Make this Subtract in SQL

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE parts 
SET    stock = (SELECT parts.stock - [item selection].quantity AS Expr1) 
FROM   parts 
       CROSS JOIN [item selection] 
WHERE  ( parts.part_type = @QuantityParameter )
```

the thing that i mind is i want went i make a new order subtract  the number on quantity that client buy on stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the first look I see the code format problem in the query, try this:

```
UPDATE parts 
SET    stock = parts.stock - [item selection].quantity
From   parts 
       CROSS JOIN [item selection] 
WHERE  ( parts.part_type = @QuantityParameter )
```

Comment: you are wlcome, happy to see you found the problem